# Querying Entries by Month and Year

Tags: craft3

Good morning, If have have a URL that passes parameters: http://url?month=January&Year=2018, how would I go about querying all entries in section where the postDate equals January 2018?

I can get the parameters by using: `craft.app.request.getParam('month')` and `craft.app.request.getParam('year')` but I can seem to figure out the correct way to only show me entries based on these parameters.

Thanks in advance.

---

I noticed a post that had the following answer and the response was that it worked. I tried it, and received the error:
`Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`.

```
{% set month = craft.request.getParam('month') %}
{% set year = craft.request.getParam('year')  %}

{% set firstDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 00:00:00') %}
{% set lastDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('last day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 23:59:59') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('yourSection').postDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth) %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon's answer is excellent, but if you want to keep the same `month` and `year` URL query params, I offer this.

The problem is that `firstDayOfMonth` and `lastDayOfMonth` are PHP class objects and can't be inlined as text. They need to be formatted as text with a `date()` or `atom` filter.

Here's your code with the filters added:

```
{% set month = craft.request.getParam('month') %}
{% set year = craft.request.getParam('year')  %}

{% set firstDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 00:00:00') %}
{% set lastDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('last day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 23:59:59') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('yourSection').postDate('and', '>= ' ~ (firstDayOfMonth|atom), '<= ' ~ (lastDayOfMonth|atom)) %}
```

You can make it extra readable by using the [`after`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#after) and [`before`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#before) methods since your query is based on Craft's `postDate` parameter.

```
{% set month = craft.request.getParam('month') %}
{% set year = craft.request.getParam('year')  %}

{% set firstDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 00:00:00') %}
{% set firstDayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfMonth | date_modify('+1 month') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries
    .section('yourSection')
    .after(firstDayOfMonth|atom)
    .before(firstDayOfNextMonth|atom)
    .all()
%}
```

I'm sure you're aware, but it's worth noting for anyone finding this answer later: This is a bit fragile. If the URL query string does not have a valid month name and four-digit year number, it'll chuck errors.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the dateCreated entry query: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#datecreated. You'll also want to change the parameter to something like `?startdate=2018-01-01&enddate=2018-01-31`.

```
{# create variables for start and end dates, getting values from params #}
{% set start = craft.app.request.getParam(startdate)|atom %}
{% set end = craft.app.request.getParam(enddate)|atom %}

{# loop through entries that match date created, and set loop to a variable #}
{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .dateCreated(['and', ">= #{start}", "< #{end}"])
    .all() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also found a solution. Seems to be working correctly. If I can simplify it, please let me know.

```
            {% set month = craft.app.request.getParam('month') ?? null %}
            {% set year = craft.app.request.getParam('year') ?? null %}

            {% set firstDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 00:00:00') %}
            {% set lastDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('last day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 23:59:59') %}

            {% set firstDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth|date('Y-m-d') %}
            {% set lastDayOfMonth = lastDayOfMonth|date('Y-m-d') %}

            {% if month|length %}
                {# {% set newsEntries = craft.entries.section('news').postDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth|date('Y-m-d'), '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth|date('Y-m-d')) %} #}
                {% paginate craft.entries.section('news').postDate(['and', ">= #{firstDayOfMonth}", "<= #{lastDayOfMonth}"]).orderBy('postDate desc').limit(10) as newsInfo, newsEntries %}
                <h3>{{ month}} {{ year }} Archives</h3>
            {% else %}
                {% paginate craft.entries.section('news').orderBy('postDate desc').limit(10) as newsInfo, newsEntries %}
                <h3>All Releases</h3>
            {% endif %}
```